# Android Retrofit I sometimes get ECONNRESET, and I don't know why

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I receive pseudo-randomely `ECONNRESET` from my backend's company. I say pseudo random because althought It doesn't happend the same way I can provoque it almost every time by launching a large amount of request.

I typicaly launch downloads from activity's life cycles events and therefore I use `Retrofit`'s `Call.enqueue()` to network on background. In the part of the code that seems to cause trouble, I'm launching a series of download (~15 REST routes for jsons and 5-6 files) from a background thread. With that scenario, the ECONNRESET apears 2 out of 3 try on one of the called REST route.

There is no more explanation server side the only thing that we logged was  read/write ECONNRESET.

Here is what I've tried :

- Update to okhttp `3.5.0` (from `3.2.0`) and retrofit `2.1.0` (from `2.0.2`)
- I added "Connection:close" int my requests header to prevent keep alive.
- I reduced my total pool to 1 : 
  `.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))`

It happend on my phone (Android 6), I don't have other phone to test the code. I've some unrelated trouble with my AVD that prevent me for testing on different android versions (soon to be fixed).

Would you know what could provoque this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the records, I was using `HttpURLConnection` in my file download method (whearas my REST api was questioned throught retrofit and okhttp), I changed it to `okHttp` and it's all good now.